# go-ethereum rpc connection via http for native dapps

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, golang, rpc

For native dapps we can establish an rcp connection over IPC using

```
conn, err := rpc.NewIPCClient("/home/karalabe/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc")
```

Now what if I want to establish an rpc connection over http i.e.

```
conn, err := rpc.NewHTTPClient("http://127.0.0.1:8545")
```

I am unaware whether than methods exists on the rpc package nor was I able to find the documentation for the rpc package. Can anyone provide examples of using HTTP connection over rpc or the full documentation of that struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3726), I think `rpc.NewIPCClien`t is deprecated and replaced by `rpc.Dial("****")`.
herefore, you can use : `client = ethclient.Dial("http://*.*.*.*:8545")`.

From this [example](https://github.com/raviupreti85/tenancy-dapp/blob/d311fad7e3bdc02a7fc336fe45c9e66f9ae60e6f/command.go) you'll find this snippet code:

```
  func getBalance(address common.Address) {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("http://localhost:8545")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    doGetBalance(client, address)
}
```

Comment: There's no err if the "http://localhost:8545" is not open. Error will be available when we use it. I recommend to use the client to check its health